# Templated class-- semicolon after constructor?

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I have a templated class:

```
    template <typename vtype>
    class BNode
    {
    public:
        BNode::BNode(std::vector<BPoly<vtype>>& thePolys) {if(thePolys.size()) Build(thePolys);}
        BNode::BNode() {}

        BPlane* mPlane=nullptr;

    //And more stuff
    };
```

When I compile, I get this error on the BPlane* mPlane=nullptr line:

```
error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'BPlane'
```

(Using Visual Studio 2019 compiler)

Why do I need a semicolon after my {}?  If I put the semicolon there, it works.  But I'm curious what the problem is because I'm worried there's some issue that will bite me later.

Comment: Is this the only error? Error C2065 usually precedes error C2146.

Comment: Why are you writing `BNode::`?

Comment: I recommend indenting the constructor's contents using multiple lines.

Comment: Where's the definition of `BPlane`?

Comment: If I add stuff required for the code to compile, then I don't have any error related to missing `;`. You have to provide minimal code that compile if we have the `;` and do not compile otherwise. Thus as written, the question is useless as it is impossible to help you since the code does not compile as written and we don't need any `;` after a constructor to make it compile if we add missing declarations and include.

Comment: Using scope resolution (`BNode::`) inside the scope is probably confusing the crap out of the compiler. Remove that stuff and see if the compiler gives better diagnostics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code compile without any error:

```
#include <vector>
class BPlane;

template <class T> class BPoly { int i; };

template <typename vtype>
class BNode
{
public:
    BNode(std::vector<BPoly<vtype>> &thePolys) { if (thePolys.size()) Build(thePolys); }
    BNode() {}

    BPlane *mPlane = nullptr;

    void Build(...) {}

    //And more stuff
};

int main()
{
    BNode<char> s;
}
```

Thus, it is impossible to guess what you have done wrong as after writing simple types for missing declaration and including `vector` the code compile without adding any `;` after a constructor.

And I have made an instantiation in `main` to be sure that the class is used.

Comment: This was the answer.  It was an artifact of moving the class out of a cpp file and into an h file for templating.  Hopefully if anyone else finds themselves in the same situation, they can find this.  I assume this wasn't a critical error, but it was worrying!